# Summation of $\dfrac{1}{1+1^2+1^4}+ \dfrac{2}{1+2^2+2^4}+\dfrac{3}{1+3^2+3^4}...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Find the sum of $\dfrac{1}{1+1^2+1^4}+ \dfrac{2}{1+2^2+2^4}+\dfrac{3}{1+3^2+3^4}...$ till n terms.

The $i^{th}$ term is given by $\dfrac{i}{1+i^2+i^4}$. I did a similar problem previously but there I was able to decompose the fraction into partial fractions. Here, I am unable to do so. What would be an efficeinent way to solve it then? (Just a hint would suffice)

Comment: Exploratory approach: If you calculate the first few terms, the partial sum seems to approach $\frac12$. The sum of the first $10$ terms is $0.495495495\ldots = \frac{55}{111} = \frac{10+10^2}{2(1+10+10^2)}$.  So take the obvious hypothesis and prove it

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $1+i^2+i^4=(1+i^2)^2-i^2$

Comment: @TobyMak Coincidence, or is it...? :), anyway the balance is up again

Comment: The coincidence is still true - because the other guy now has 1 vote and I have 2 votes.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the partial fraction decomposition by writing $x^4+x^2+1$ as the product of two quadratics $(Ax^2+Bx+C)(Dx^2+Ex+F)$, and doing some casework to get the variables. Since the coefficient of $x^4$ is $1$, and $1$'s only factor is $1$, then both $A$ and $D$ equal $1$. We then have:

$$(x^2+Bx+C)(x^2+Ex+F)$$

The coefficient of the constant term is $1$, so following the same logic, we get:

$$(x^2+Bx+1)(x^2+Ex+1)$$

Since there is no $x^3$ term, and we know that the only ways of getting a $x^3$ is from $Bx*x^2$ and $x^2*Ex$, then these terms must cancel each other. We can conclude $B = -E$, and we obtain:

$$(x^2+Bx+1)(x^2-Bx+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow (x^4-Bx^3+x^2)+(Bx^3-B^2x+Bx)+(x^2-Bx+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow x^4+(2-B^2)x^2+1$$

Then since $(2-B^2)x^2=x^2$, then $2-B^2=1$, or $B=1$. Then collecting all the variables into the same expression, we get that the factorisation of $x^4+x^2+1$ equals $(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$. You can multiply this out to verify my answer if you wish to.

Done!

Comment: You made a nice answer and a very good comment to a previous so-called "answer". By the way $\to +1$.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici, it's nice for you to say that since my experience with posting these kinds of answers has been quite negative.